# using scala variable in shell script

Tags: scala, shell, azure-databricks

I am running a databricks notebook from Azure devops pipeline using Execute Databricks notebook task. I am passing vertical name and branch name to my notebooks. Using dbutils am able to get the required values. I have Scala code and shell script code in the same notebook in different cells. I have to use the notebook parameters in the shell script which is in same notebook different cell.
Can someone please suggest me how i can use notebook parameters in the shell script

```
%scala
val verticalName =  dbutils.widgets.get("vertical") 
val branchName =  dbutils.widgets.get("branch")
println(verticalName)
println(branchName)
%sh
echo $verticalName 
echo $branchName
```

Comment: Could you please share solution here. If you got.

Comment: I tried with python. Below is the code
` import os
vertical=dbutils.widgets.get("vertical")
os.environ['verticalName']=vertical `